# not able to create datasource via jython

Tags: python, websphere, wsadmin

```
jdbc = AdminConfig.getid('/JDBCProvider:Oracle JDBC Driver/')
AdminConfig.createDatasource(jdbc, '[-name %jdbcDS% -jndiName jdbc/%jdbcDS% -dataStoreHelperClassName com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.Oracle10gDataStoreHelper -componentManagedAuthenticationAlias %PROFILE_NAME%/Cramer_User -configureResourceProperties [[URL java.lang.String jdbc:oracle:thin:@%DB_HOST%:1521:%DB_SID%]]]')
```

gives below error (I have replaced the real values with some dummy values):

```
WASX7015E: Exception running command: "AdminConfig.createDatasource(jdbc, '[-name %jdbcDS% -jndiName jdbc/%jdbcDS% -dataStoreHelperClassName com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.Oracle10gDataStoreHelper -componentManagedAuthenticationAlias %PROFILE_NAME%/Cramer_User -configureResourceProperties [[URL java.lang.String jdbc:oracle:thin:@%DB_HOST%:1521:%DB_SID%]]]')"; exception information:
 com.ibm.bsf.BSFException: exception from Jython:
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in ?
AttributeError: createDatasource
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `AdminTask` instead of `AdminConfig`.

Answer (score -1):

```
jdbcProviderId = AdminConfig.getid('/JDBCProvider:Oracle JDBC Driver/')
AdminConfig.create('DataSource', jdbcProviderId, '[-name %jdbcDS% -jndiName jdbc/%jdbcDS% -dataStoreHelperClassName com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.Oracle10gDataStoreHelper -componentManagedAuthenticationAlias %PROFILE_NAME%/Cramer_User -configureResourceProperties [[URL java.lang.String jdbc:oracle:thin:@%DB_HOST%:1521:%DB_SID%]]]')
```